# Multiple django scripts and servers with same project settings

Tags: django

As far as I know there's no limit to the number of scripts and server instances using the same django project settings and apps to query, alter and save new model instances (save DB related limitations of course).

Is this true?
If not, what are the limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true and the recommended way to scale Django beyond one server. Synchronization problems may arise if you are using `LocMemCache` (limited to local memory), or saving uploaded files with `FileField`, which saves files to the local filesystem by default. Other similar issues may also crop up.